# LibGDX overlaps methods arguments

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm following a set of LibGDX tutorials. As I understand it, the `overlaps` method operates on a rectangle object, and takes another rectangle object as an parameter, as I can see from [this page](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html).

I am using the method like this:

```
if(bill.bounds.overlaps(steve.bounds)){
    System.out.println("Stop touching me bill!");
}
```

I keep getting an error that says:

> the methods overlaps(rectangles) is undefined for the type rectangles.

Comment: is "rectangles" type of com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your import.

Go somewhere up in your class and search for the rectangle import, delete that line and replace it with the libGDX rectangle class (import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle)